# How to create a bevel/sink effect on a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects

Can anyone explain how to create a bevel and sink effect on a shape like the picture below?

[image]

Comment: What is the effect you are looking for? Sorry, the picture isn't very clear :)

Comment: Hello André, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help]. For now, I'd like to advise you to [edit] some more detail to your question, so we can identify what it is exactly that you want to achieve. Thanks! Feel free to join us in [chat] if you have more questions once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hello Vincent,Thank you for your answer, I need the effect fot cutting out of the object so it looks like the lower parts is 2mm down. Sorry I cannot decribe it better. Drawing a shape like that is aslo what I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I hope my answer has helped you along anyway. And, if, judging by your name, explaining in Dutch works better, don't hesitate to do so in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I'm reading your reference picture correctly, you are looking after a `Bevel & Emboss` effect, possibly combined with an `Inner Shadow`.

- Draw your shape as a single layer in Photoshop. It doesn't matter if it's a shape layer or a pixel layer, as long as the pixels that don't belong to the shape are transparent;
- Open the `Layers` palette by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> or choosing <kbd>Window > Layers</kbd>;
- <kbd>Double click</kbd> the empty part of your layer's entry in the `Layers` palette. That is, anything besides the layer's miniature(s) or its name. This opens up the `Layer Style` dialogue box.
- Click on `Bevel & Emboss`. Be sure to click the words, not the checkbox, so the effect's settings appear.
- Play around with the effects to your heart's desire until you achieve your desired look. Checking 'Preview' on the right of the dialogue box might help you seeing what you're doing. For this specific effect, I'd advice you to choose 'Inner Bevel' for the `Style`, a relatively big `size` and one of the weirder `Gloss Contour`s.
- Apply and change your `Inner Shadow` effect the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I need to pratice a lot to get the final result, you are a big help to me. Thank you very much.